# dart "part of" can't used twice in a file

Tags: dart

I have a class named `_AppColors`. it contains all colors used in the application. I want to force developers to read colors from `Theme` that's why I made this class private. now I want to access this class from two files. but it can be only `part of` one file. how can I handle this?

app_colors.dart:

```
part of 'color_extention.dart';

class _AppColors {
   ...
```

app_theme.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

part 'app_colors.dart';

extension MultiThemeColorExtension on ThemeData {
   ...
```

color_extention.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

part 'app_colors.dart';

const TextTheme _textThemeLight = TextTheme(
   ...
```

but I have to add `part of 'color_extention.dart';` in app_colors.dart which I can't. any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private symbols are private to the *library*.  Normally a Dart library is a single `.dart` file, but `part` is used to specify that a library comprise multiple `.dart` files (and conversely, `part of` is used to specify that a `.dart` file is part of the specified library).

It doesn't make sense for a Dart file to be part of multiple libraries.  If you want to share a private class with multiple `.dart` files, your typical options are:

- Make *all* of those `.dart` files part of the same library.
- Make your class public instead but discourage using them.  Packages typically do this [by placing internal implementation files in `lib/src/`](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/package-layout#implementation-files) and exporting only the symbols intended for public consumption.